# Resue Temporary Queue Apache CXF in JMS transport

Tags: spring, jms, cxf

How can the temporary queue generated by Apache CXF during web service call can be reused so that no more temporary queues are generated in each request reply operation.

Comment: Then it's not temporary. Are you using a temporary queue to implement a synchronous request-response cycle?

Comment: Yes...the temporary queues generated by cxf are not deleted by the session that created it on JBOSS..